# Kivy running but no content shown on GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn about kivy and mobile app, however after creating a simple code base on the tutorial, the content/s is not showing on the gui.

Pls see image below:

[image]

I was able to install the kivy pip after knowing that it is only supported at 3.7-3.10. Installed tkinter and ffpyplayer also upgraded sdl2 but still not showing content

[image]

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class childApp(GridLayout):
    def __int__(self,**kwargs):
        super(childApp, self).__init__()
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text = 'Student Name'))
        self.s_name = TextInput( )
        self.add_widget(self.s_name)
    
        self.add_widget(Label(text = 'Student Marks'))
        self.s_marks = TextInput( )
        self.add_widget(self.s_marks)

        self.add_widget(Label(text = 'Student Gender'))
        self.s_gender = TextInput( )
        self.add_widget(self.s_gender)

class parentApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return childApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parentApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simple typo in childApp class. it should be `__init__` not `__int__`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class childApp(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(childApp, self).__init__()
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text = 'Student Name'))
        self.s_name = TextInput( )
        self.add_widget(self.s_name)
        
        self.add_widget(Label(text = 'Student Marks'))
        self.s_marks = TextInput( )
        self.add_widget(self.s_marks)

        self.add_widget(Label(text = 'Student Gender'))
        self.s_gender = TextInput( )
        self.add_widget(self.s_gender)

class parentApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return childApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parentApp().run()
```

Comment: You may this site below for the code, Thanks
https://github.com/gnarlyeah/kivy/blob/main/Test.py

Comment: this should work now

Comment: Oh wow, What an unreasonable mistake. so sorry for the trouble, and thank you for the help